# Calling bokeh api from python / flask for charts -- becoming slower with each call

Tags: python, charts, flask, bokeh

I am running a flask application which makes calls to a bokeh api for generating charts to be rendered in html. The first time I generate the chart, it is taking about 0.07s. The second time, about 0.14s. The third time about 0.21s, and so on. I must be doing something wrong. Wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to fix this. Thank You. Neela.

Comment: Can you post the code for generating the bokeh plot?

Comment: p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',y_axis_label='Value of $1 invested at the start of the period')

Comment: p.line(days, data, legend="Port", line_width=2, color='green')

Comment: p.line(days, spx, legend="SPX", line_width=2,color='red')

Comment: p.line(days, blend, legend="60% Stock/40% Bond Blend", line_width=2,color='blue')

Comment: p.legend.border_line_color = "None"

Comment: p.legend.location = "top_left"

Comment: html = file_html(p, CDN)

Comment: return html                         . This code is called from a view function in Flask. There is actually an intermediate function that generates the data.

Comment: This is the line that calls the above code from the intermediate function:      chart = charting.chart(dts, cum_port, av_port, st_port, cum_spx, cum_blend, av_spx, st_spx, av_blend, st_blend,'Suggested Strategy', 'US S&P', '60/40 US Stock/Bond blend')

Comment: The intermediate function I mentioned is called from the the Flask view function and generates the data that is fed to the charting function.

Comment: While all the lines are taking slightly longer with each call, it is really the html = file_html(p, CDN) call that is taken the longest time and increasing at the fastest pace with each additional call.

Comment: If I use Figure instead of figure, the problem seems to go away -- based on a thread on Github that I read.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem. It turns out Bokeh stores data in its curdoc across requests.

I fix this by manually clearing bokeh document everytime at the end of each request with:   `curdoc().clear()`